# downgrade to 22.10

Tags: graphics, printing, crash

I am having many problems with Ubuntu 23.04. Ubuntu crashes several times a day. I use GIMP and Inkscape mostly. I am working with a new install and my  previous PC didn't have problem,s (22.10). Today my programs don't recognize my printer, HP 610. Is my only option to reformat and reinstall 22.10? There must be a work around.
Thanks guys.

Comment: Of course you have other options. One obvious alternative is that you can troubleshoot the problem(s). Maybe some have easy fixes. Maybe some require filing a bug report. We cannot offer more specific advice based upon the very limited information you have provided so far. See https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on crafting a good question likely to get you useful answers.

Comment: Unfortunately, downgrade is not supported. Instead of installing 22.10 which will soon become EOL, it would be recommended to install 22.04 instead. 22.04 is a LTS release and will be supported for 5 years and also eligible for extended support beyond that.  LTS releases are designed to be more stable and less experimental than interim releases like 22.10 and 23.04.

Comment: You can *non-destructively* re-install Ubuntu Desktop systems, and as the installation media does not check release info, you can install a newer or even older release using this.  I've done this many many times, including on my primary PC (*eg. I didn't like 11.10 so returned to 11.04 long ago*) BUT there can be problems when going backwards (*as I discovered in my 11.10->11.04 example & why I remember it!*), and these are **not** documented (*as it's not a supported path*) and checks are required on a package level.. Your mention of *previous PC* implies to me release may not be your issue

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and formatted and reinstalled 22.04 and all my software.
Thanks for the interest to help
Dave